# jQuery append() not printing table properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I need to show a `table` on AJAX success and I'm using the `append()` method.
However the end result looks weird because the first row of the table is normal size (full weight of `div` element) and other rows just tiny columns. I think something is wrong with output:

```
success: function(data) {
    var $el = $("#div-right");
    $el.empty();
    i = 0;
    $el.append('<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Description</td> <td>Status</td><td></td></tr>');

    $.each(data, function() {
        if (data[i].status == '0') {  
            statusflag = '<td id="green"> Active </td>';
        } else {
            statusflag = '<td id="red-b"> Inactive </td>';
        }

        if (data[i].status == '0')  {
            action = '<a href="?category-action=' + data[i].id + '&deletetoken=' + data[i].token + '" class="deactivate">'+ '\ <img src="../images/delete.png" width="20" height="20" class="delete">'+ '</a>';
        } else {
            action = '<a href="?category-action=' + data[i].id + '&deletetoken=' + data[i].token + '" class="activate">'+ '\ <img src="../images/active2.png" width="20" height="20" class="delete">' + '</a>';
        }

        $el.append('<tr data-id=' + data[i].id + ' data-token=' + data[i].token + '><td>' + data[i].id + '</td>\n\<td>' + data[i].description + '</td>' + statusflag + '<td>' + action + '</td></tr>');
        i = ++ i; 
    });

    $el.append('</table>');
    $("#div-right").show();  
},
```

Comment: You have to have closing tag of table in the same `append`... And then append just each tr to `$el.find('table')`.

Comment: @Legionar what do you mean? table closing tag is outside loop

Comment: You can only append entire elements to the DOM at a time. Appending an opening and closing tag separately will give you two `<table>` elements as the HTML renderer attempts to fix your broken HTML

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan correctly pointed.

Comment: Ok i understand now thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, you have to have closing tag of table in the same `append`... And then append just each tr to `$el.find('table')`. So change your code to this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var $el = $("#div-right");
    $el.empty();
    i = 0;
    $el.append('<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Description</td> <td>Status</td><td></td></tr></table>');

    $.each(data, function() {
        if (data[i].status == '0') {  
            statusflag = '<td id="green"> Active </td>';
        } else {
            statusflag = '<td id="red-b"> Inactive </td>';
        }

        if (data[i].status == '0')  {
            action = '<a href="?category-action=' + data[i].id + '&deletetoken=' + data[i].token + '" class="deactivate">'+ '\ <img src="../images/delete.png" width="20" height="20" class="delete">'+ '</a>';
        } else {
            action = '<a href="?category-action=' + data[i].id + '&deletetoken=' + data[i].token + '" class="activate">'+ '\ <img src="../images/active2.png" width="20" height="20" class="delete">' + '</a>';
        }

        $el.find('table tr:last').after('<tr data-id=' + data[i].id + ' data-token=' + data[i].token + '><td>' + data[i].id + '</td>\n\<td>' + data[i].description + '</td>' + statusflag + '<td>' + action + '</td></tr>');
        i = ++ i; 
    });

    $("#div-right").show();  
},
```

Also you have to use `.after` to add rows after the last `tr`.

Comment: It needs to be `$el.filter('table')` as table is the root node.

Comment: `$el.find('table tr:last')` could be, or not?

Answer (score 2):

As above comment say, appending an opening and closing tag separately will give you two separated `<table>` nodes, you could create a `table` node separately `var table = $('</table>');` and append all rows to it, then finally append it to `$el` :

```
var $el = $("#div-right");
$el.empty();
i = 0;

var table = $('</table>'); //Create table node

//Append nodes to the created table
table.append('<tr><td>ID</td><td>Description</td> <td>Status</td><td></td></tr>'); 

$.each(data, function() {
  if (data[i].status == '0'){  
    statusflag = '<td id="green"> Active </td>';} else {statusflag = '<td id="red-b"> Inactive </td>';
  }

  if (data[i].status == '0'){
    action = '<a href="?category-action=' + data[i].id + '&deletetoken=' + data[i].token + '" class="deactivate">'+ '\<img src="../images/delete.png" width="20" height="20" class="delete">'+ '</a>';
  }else{
    action = '<a href="?category-action=' + data[i].id + '&deletetoken=' + data[i].token + '" class="activate">'+ '\<img src="../images/active2.png" width="20" height="20" class="delete">'+ '</a>';
  }

  //Append nodes to the created table
  table.append('<tr data-id='+ data[i].id +' data-token='+data[i].token +  '><td>'+data[i].id+'</td>\n\<td>'+data[i].description+'</td>'+ statusflag +'<td>'+ action +'</td></tr>');

  i = ++ i; 
});

$el.append(table); //Append table to '$el' element

$("#div-right").show();
```

Hope this helps.